# Using a local Wifi that has no gateway/internet connection while using mobile data for internet access in an android app (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, networking, mobile, wifi

I am trying to connect a hardware (ifm ecomat) in a local wifi network that has no internet gateway/access.
Nevertheless, I need internet connection for the rest of the app using mobile data.

On the Android 9 Samsung Active Tab Pro I am not able to leave the gateway field empty (static ip configuration). If I try to remove it it automatically enters the first IP of the subnet as gateway.

Therefore, when I try to  connect to the internet with mobile data and wifi. It tries to communicate over the wifi network with the gateway that is not existent.

If I switch "allways prefere mobile data for this app" on, I'm not able to communicate with my local network anymore.

Any idea how to get rid of the gateay or implement a routing table in the flutter app?